# replacing some text in square brakets in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have this string that I get from running `jack_lsp`.

```
a2j:Arturia BeatStep [28] (capture): Arturia BeatStep MIDI 1
```

in a xml file, I save the connections state from a  previous jack session.

```
<connection>
    <output>a2j:Arturia BeatStep [20] (capture): Arturia BeatStep MIDI 1</output>
    <input>starmaze:midi_to_slave_1</input>
</connection>
```

You may have noticed, that between the previous session (saved in the xml file) and the current session, the value in `[]` (square brakets) has been changed.
asu such I am trying to update the value in the file  whenever I want to load it.

To do that I have the following bash snippet:

```
ARTURIA_CHAN=$( jack_lsp | grep Arturia | grep capture | sed -e 's/^.*\[\(.*\)\].*$/\1/' )
ARTURIA_XMLCHAN=$( cat "${ofname}" | grep Arturia | grep capture | sed -e 's/^.*\[\(.*\)\].*$/\1/' )
if [ "${ARTURIA_CHAN}" != "${ARTURIA_XMLCHAN}" ]; then
   sed -e "s/\[$ARTURIA_XMLCHAN\]/\[$ARTURIA_CHAN\]/g" -i.bak1-art "${ofname}"
   echo "changing arturia from ${ARTURIA_XMLCHAN} to ${ARTURIA_CHAN}"
fi
```

`ofname` is the "output filename" and it is basically the xml file.

The 2 variables seem to get the expected values (what's within the `[]`), but the sed operation either does not work correctly , or does not save the file in the end. I can't figure out that it is though. Is it more apparent to you perhaps?

thank you.

Comment: Put `set -x` in the script so you can see a trace of the command executions, to see what substitutions are being done.

Answer (score 2):

Better use an XML parser with a [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression to modify the XML file. One example with [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) :

```
$ xmlstarlet edit -L -u "/connection/output[contains(., "Arturia")]" -v "remplacement_string" file.xml
```